# BufferedReader doesn't wait till input is done

Tags: java

I have a problem with my BufferedReader which suppose to read all the time till I tell do not do it. But it is not. Why in program is shutting down and doesn't wait till I will type "true or false"?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    double a;
    double b;
    char ch=' ';
    try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((System.in))))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Введите a: ");
            a = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Введите b: ");
            b = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

            System.out.println("Введите символ арифметической операции, которую хотите произвести с выражением a{}b: * / + -.");
            ch = (char) br.read();
            switch (ch) {
                case '+':
                    System.out.println(a + b);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    System.out.println(a - b);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    System.out.println(a * b);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    System.out.println((b != 0) ? (a / b) : "Нельзя делить на 0!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели не поддерживаемые символы!");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("Хотите повторить ввод? (true, false)");

            String str = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("str " + str);
            if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(str)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current output and how far does the program get?  Do you actually enter a character when prompted to do so?  Are there any exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter any input, you also enter a newline character which is being read by this line `ch = (char) br.read();` in your present code.

So, to avoid it, use the below code to accept the operator char (* / + -):

```
ch = (char) br.readLine().charAt(0);   // charAt(0) returns first char from line and leaves out the newline char
```

Or another solution would be to use `br.readLine();` as shown:

```
ch = (char) br.read();
br.readLine(); // here
```

which will consume the line with newline character met after you enter an operator char.

**Output:**

```
Введите a: // Enter a
12
Введите b: // Enter b
13
// Enter symbol for arithmetic operation you want to perform with the expression of a {} b: * / + -.
Введите символ арифметической операции, которую хотите произвести с выражением a{}b: * / + -.
+
25.0
Хотите повторить ввод? (true, false) // Do you want to re-enter?
true
str true
Введите a: // Enter a
```

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE

```
String str = String.valueOf(br.readLine());
```

then it is working.

Comment: I disagree.  The original order seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enter another line after `String str = br.readLine();`

lets say

```
String str1 = br.readLine();
 if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(str1)) {
                    break;
                }
```

working code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{


        double a;
        double b;
        char ch=' ';
        try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((System.in))))
        {while (true)

        {
            System.out.println("Введите a: ");
            a = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Введите b: ");
            b = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

            System.out.println("Введите символ арифметической операции, которую хотите произвести с выражением a{}b: * / + -.");
            ch = (char) br.read();
            switch (ch) {
                case '+':
                    System.out.println(a + b);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    System.out.println(a - b);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    System.out.println(a * b);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    System.out.println((b != 0) ? (a / b) : "Нельзя делить на 0!");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели не поддерживаемые символы!");
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("Хотите повторить ввод? (true, false)");

            String str = br.readLine();
            String str1=br.readLine();// this line is added
            System.out.println("str " + str);
            if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(str1)) { //this line is modified
                break;
            }
        }


        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Orions I did not understand for what purpose she is printing in console. If she wanted to know the input then she can do `System.out.println("str1 " + str1);`

Comment: @Orions I ran the code before posting here. if you type true at end then loop will continue